# How to substitute two variables in one loop in Stata

Tags: stata

I want to be able to carry out the following idea in Stata. I have a bunch of paired names. For instance `Ryan` and `King` is a pair. In a  pseudo code

```
keep  if product_name == "i" | product_name == "j"
```

where `Ryan` should substitute the `i` and `King` sub the `j`. I want to have a loop that can do this for multiple pairs of the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use *parallel lists*. Some technique:

```
local agrp "cat dog cow pig"
local bgrp "meow woof moo oinkoink"

local n : word count `agrp'

forvalues i = 1/`n' {
      local a : word `i' of `agrp'
      local b : word `i' of `bgrp'
      display "`a' says `b'"
}
```

Substitute the `display` line with whatever you want.

This is a [Stata FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/looping-over-parallel-lists/).